# deb package for new software for ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, package, deb

I want to build mysoftware.deb package for ubuntu and debian.

Every tutorial about building **deb** files is for maintaining not your own software, just for making deb files for ready source code. In my case I want to have building and installing software together with building deb package in one Makefile. So I can:

```
make
make install
make deb
```

How to write that makefile? I'm assuming I have debian/* files ready and under my version control system.

Very mysterious to me is creating that mysoftware.orig.tar.gz and uncompressing it back so I can invoke debuild inside that folder. !?!?....

Does anybody have some short and accurate documentation?

Comment: If you already have a `debian/rules` file, what do you need help with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have a `debian/rules` file and just want to create a simple target to create your Debian package from your main `Makefile`, you could do something like this:

```
.PHONY: deb
deb:
        # maybe invoke dch here to add a new entry to debian/Changelog ...
        debuild -us -uc -rfakeroot -b
```

Just make sure this is not your default target (assuming your `debian/rules` invokes the main `Makefile`, as it usually does).

---

With `dh-make` you can create a simple "native" package, which means there is no upstream.

```
debian$ dh_make --native --other-options ...
```

I agree that the upstream assumption is kind of distracting.  On the other hand, making a native package is so simple you hardly need much of a tutorial.

Comment: Above command generates debian/* files. I have those files ready. How to generate my_1.0.deb package (I need command to insert in my Makefile).

Comment: Updated the answer slightly.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Your update works. Option I was missing is -b. Without it debuild asks about missing *.orig.* file. But "man debuild" doesn't list that switch... What means -b ?

Comment: One more important thing. That debuild command generates *.deb file in parent directory, which is out of my code tree. How I can change this?

Comment: You cannot really AFAIK; just move it when you are done, or make a superfluous parent directory.

Comment: `-b` is a `dpkg-buildpackage` option properly; many of the programs in the dpkg toolchain have options which are simply passed on to one or more of the lower-level tools they invoke, so you have to chase forward links between the man pages.